# How to Iterate through an array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Im learning swift and am having a problem Iterating through an array.
Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
func orderStringByOccurence(stringArray: [String]) -> [String: Int]{
    var stringDictionary: [String: Int] = [:]
    for i in 0...stringArray.count {
        if stringDictionary[stringArray[i]] == nil {
            stringDictionary[stringArray[i]] = 1
            stringDictionary
        } else {
            stringDictionary[stringArray[i]]! += 1
        }
    }
    return stringDictionary
}
```

I don't get an error until I try to call this function. Then I get this error:

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

I have tried debugging and found that i get the same error when i try this:

```
for i in 0...arrayFromString.count{
    print(arrayFromString[i])
}
```

So how do I iterate through this array?
Thanks for helping out a new

Comment: Thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to change

```
for i in 0...arrayFromString.count
```

to

```
for i in 0..<arrayFromString.count
```

As it is now, you iterate through the array and then one past the end.

You can also use a different style of for loop, which is perhaps a little better:

```
func orderStringByOccurence(stringArray: [String]) -> [String: Int] {
    var stringDictionary: [String: Int] = [:]
    for string in stringArray {
        if stringDictionary[string] == nil {
            stringDictionary[string] = 1
        } else {
            stringDictionary[string]! += 1
        }
    }
    return stringDictionary
}
```

Also, you can simplify your logic a bit:

```
for string in stringArray {
    stringDictionary[string] = stringDictionary[string] ?? 0 + 1
}
```

**Update** - For the sake of completeness, I thought I'd add a reduce example here as well.  Note that as of Swift 5.1 return statements in single line functions can be implied ([SE-0255](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0255-omit-return.md)).

```
func orderStringByOccurence(stringArray: [String]) -> [String: Int] {
    stringArray.reduce([:]) { result, string in result.merging([string: 1], uniquingKeysWith: +)}
}
```

Answer (score 23):

A few more approaches:

```
let array = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

You can use `forEach` with trailing closure syntax:

```
array.forEach { item in
    print(item)
}
```

You can use the `$0` shorthand:

```
array.forEach {
    print($0)
}
```

And if you need the indexes, you can use `enumerate()`:

```
array.enumerate().forEach { itemTuple in
    print("\(itemTuple.element) is at index \(itemTuple.index)")
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems you're out of index. A more swift-like approach would be in my opinion not to use the count but to do range-based.

```
var stringArray = ["1", "2", "3"]
for string in stringArray
{
    print(string)
}
```