# Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, watchos

I'm struggling to output a random String inside the View.

Due to the error:

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'View

I've learned that View isn't the appropriate place to write down the functions itself.

What should I do to output `itemX.randomElement()` and `itemY.randomElement()`?

```
struct SummaryView: View {
    var avgValue = 1.5
    var roundedKarvonenValue: Double
    var itemX = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
    var itemY = ["I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P"]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                if workoutManager.averageHeartRate < roundedKarvonenValue {
                    print(itemX.randomElement()!)
                } else {
                    print(itemY.randomElement()!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can print statement like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63182458/14733292

Comment: Why do you need to print, why not use `Text()` instead?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a great deal to unpack in this question, but we will start with the simple first. `Views` are for displaying something on screen. Nothing more. The reason you are having issues with the `print()` statements is that they are for printing to the console, not the screen. Therefore, the compiler gives you an error. To fix this, use `Text` like @JoakimDanielson said:

```
struct SummaryView: View {
    var workoutManager: WorkoutManager //This var must be declared
    
    var avgValue = 1.5
    var roundedKarvonenValue: Double
    var itemX = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
    var itemY = ["I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                if workoutManager.averageHeartRate < roundedKarvonenValue{
                    Text(itemX[0])
                } else {
                    Text(itemY[0])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As to your second part as to where to place your functions, is not as clear cut. You should look up MVVM architecture to gain an understanding of the standard way to structure your app in SwiftUI. Right now, you are simply displaying data from `HealthKit` using Apple's WWDC `class WorkoutManager`(I presume).

At the very basic level, if your function has to do with changing how the data is displayed, it stays in the `View`. If the function fundamentally changes something about your `Model` or is needed by multiple views, it should go into the `Model`. That is a judgment call.

So, for your code, you are showing a random element from a variable declared in a view. That is all local stuff, so the function stays in the view. Adding the `func randomElement()` and cleaning your code up a bit more leaves you with this:

```
struct SummaryView: View {
    // If you are not changing the variables, declare them as constants. This uses less memory.
    let workoutManager: WorkoutManager
    let avgValue = 1.5
    let roundedKarvonenValue: Double
    let itemX = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
    let itemY = ["I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                // I turned your if statement into a Terniary Conditional Operator to shrink the amount of code.
                Text(workoutManager.averageHeartRate < roundedKarvonenValue ? randomElement(itemX) : randomElement(itemY))
            }
        }
    }
                     
    func randomElement(_ stringArray: [String]) -> String {
        let end = stringArray.count - 1
        let index = Int.random(in: 0...end)
        return stringArray[index]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 35):

You can use print statements inside views like this:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    if workoutManager.averageHeartRate < roundedKarvonenValue {
        let _ = print(itemX.randomElement()!)
    } else {
        let _ = print(itemY.randomElement()!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea why this works? I didn't know print return values!

Comment: @PhuahYeeKeat check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63182458/8541799

Comment: `print()` returns `Void`, `let _ = …` ignores the returned `Void`. Also, the presence of `Void` indicates that the `View` has some possible side-effect.

Answer (score 4):

For every one else facing this error you can not run code inside the views body.

either use the the let _ = func() approach

or

we can run code in side such event ie

```
.onTapGesture { self.func() }
.onDisappear{ self.func() }
.onAppear{ self.func() }
```

for reference visit this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63232464/swiftui-how-can-i-call-a-function-in-my-view)

Answer (score 1):

Another reason could be you are attempting to iterate over a collection in a functional nature.

Run into this sometimes when I switch between UIKit and SwiftUI and forget :)

Example:

Using `collection.forEach { item in` in a view/stack

Comment: So, I was in a class{} function(), so, "conforming to view" didn't make sense. This answer helped me. 
Instead of: 
ForEach(self.items) { item in
I used:
items.forEach { item in.

As per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554278/how-to-iterate-through-an-array-in-swift